# Ember include id property in POST payload

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following models:

1. A "generic" model `reference` used for listing values
2. `user` model

Now, `user` can have many `departments` whose model is exactly `reference`.

How can I declare in `user` model that the `departments` can have many `reference` objects?

I tried the following but can't make it work:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    departments: DS.hasMany('reference')
});
```

For what it's worth, this question stemmed from needing to include the id in the POST payload using Ember Data. My original `user` model is like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    departments: DS.attr()
});
```

Problem with above model, whenever I save a record, it doesn't include the ID of the references in the payload even though they're already loaded in the store.

Do I need to create a custom serializer for the `user` model?

Comment: POST is for creating new records, which do not yet have an ID by definition.

Comment: Hi @torazaburo. The IDs I need for the departments are available because I fetched them already before creating a user record.

Comment: [Following Documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/models/relationships/) `DS.hasMany('reference')` is correct to declare a One-to-Many or Many-to-Many relationship. Adapters shipped with Ember Data could handle this relationships. Could you please provide more code? Please also check with [Ember Inspector](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/ember-inspector/data/) how your data in store looks like and if relationship is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are after the [EmbeddedRecordsMixin.](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html)

With it you can tell the serializer to include the entire model or its' id. Something like this:

```
//serializer/user.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    departments: { embedded: 'always' }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello, @carcel. Thanks for this. Got it working with the `embedded: 'always'` option